# Save as PDF in Landscape

Tags: excel, vba

How can I pdf multiple sheets in my Workbook into one pdf in landscape format? Here is what I have. I am missing the landscape syntax -

```
Sub CompileReport()

    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="F:\Report\Test" & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False


End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub CompileReport()
    Dim mySheets As Variant, sh

    mySheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    For Each sh In mySheets
        Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Next

    Sheets(mySheets).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="F:\Report\Test" & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with this code: ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="F:\Report\Test" & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

Comment: what is the error? do you actually have folder `Report` on drive `F`?

Comment: That was it. I didn't have the Report folder created. Thanks!