# Export excel graphs to horizontal PDF with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have the following VBA code that basically takes the graphs from an excel workbook's sheet and paste them into a PDF document:

```
Sub Graphics()

    Dim s As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Shape
    Dim tp As Long
    Dim File As String
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim Path As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Here I define where the excel file is:
    SourcePath = "\\ukfs1\users\gabriem\Documents\Misproyectos\BigPromotions\QAPromo"

    'Name of excel file that contains the graphs:
    File = "graphicator.xlsx"

    'Open the excel file:
    Set s = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath & "\" & File)

    'Name of the PDF I will create with the excel graphs:
    NewFileName = "\\ukfs1\users\gabriem\Documents\Mis proyectos\BigPromotions\QAPromo\test_pdf.pdf"

    'Name of the excel sheet I want to export to PDF:
    Set ws = s.Sheets("Negocios")

    Set wsTemp = s.Sheets.Add

    tp = 2
    ts = 5

    'Copy-Pasting process:
    With wsTemp
        For Each chrt In ws.Shapes
            chrt.Copy
            wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
            Selection.Top = tp
            Selection.Left = ts
            tp = tp + Selection.Height + 50
        Next
    End With

    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
       IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    wsTemp.Delete

 LetsContinue:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue

End Sub
```

Although the code works fine, the output it generates is not graphically adequate because many of the graphs were cut (half of them were in another page). So, I I want the generated PDF to be horizontal, but have not been able to find an answer. Is not a problem from the excel but from the new PDF the VBA code creates:

[image]
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save as PDF in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118877/save-as-pdf-in-landscape)

Comment: you control most of the layout via it's PageSetup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had similar problems with generating PDFs from charts. The solution is to use `ChartObject` instead of `Shape`, and use `.CopyImage` to get a picture of the chart instead of trying to copy the actual chart. So the code would look more like:

```
Dim chrt as ChartObject
:
For Each chrt in ws.ChartObjects
    chrt.CopyPicture
    wsTemp.Paste
    Selection.Top = tp
    Selection.Left = ts
    ts = ts + Selection.Width + 50
 Next
```

Then you should also set the print area in the worksheet, and the page setup to paginate the document how you want the pdf to appear - use landscape format (if that's what you mean by "horizontal"). Have you got more charts than will fit on a page? If so, you will need to check the cumulative width to ensure that the charts do not cross page boundaries.