# How do I export all my graphs in excel into a single pdf without it being cut?

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to Excel VBA. Currently, I am trying to produce a PDF output where all my graphs in Excel are printed onto the pdf.

So far, I have tried using one of the codes posted on ([Export excel graphs to horizontal PDF with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47781303/export-excel-graphs-to-horizontal-pdf-with-vba) by Gabriela M and John RC). The code works well, however, as I have about 100+ graphs, a lot of graphs at the bottom of the page tends to be cut into half and be spread over 2 pages.

For my PDF output, I am trying to get a page where I can print a heading (Text from a cell) followed by my 4 graphs (Preferably in a 2x2 Landscape format) without my graphs being spread over 2 pages. May I check if anyone have any idea how to fix this please? Thank you in advance!

```
Sub Graphics()

    Dim s As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As ChartObjects
    Dim tp As Long
    Dim File As String
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim Path As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Here I define where the excel file is:
    SourcePath = "\\ukfs1\users\gabriem\Documents\Misproyectos\BigPromotions\QAPromo"

    'Name of excel file that contains the graphs:
    File = "graphicator.xlsx"

    'Open the excel file:
    Set s = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath & "\" & File)

    'Name of the PDF I will create with the excel graphs:
    NewFileName = "\\ukfs1\users\gabriem\Documents\Mis proyectos\BigPromotions\QAPromo\test_pdf.pdf"

    'Name of the excel sheet I want to export to PDF:
    Set ws = s.Sheets("Negocios")

    Set wsTemp = s.Sheets.Add

    tp = 2
    ts = 5

    'Copy-Pasting process:
    With wsTemp
    For Each chrt in ws.ChartObjects
    chrt.CopyPicture
    wsTemp.Paste
    Selection.Top = tp
    Selection.Left = ts
    ts = ts + Selection.Width + 50
        Next
    End With

    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
       IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    wsTemp.Delete

 LetsContinue:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to experiment with adjusting the location of the page breaks.  After adding each shape, check to see if it spans a page break, and if it does then adjust the position of that break to before the shape you just added.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thanks for the suggestion. As I am relatively new to VBA, I am not very sure how the code works. How should I go about adjusting the page breaks please? I tried toggling with the values of tp and ts but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you only want 4 plots per page?  Does your current code already lay them out as you want (apart from misplaced page breaks)?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, yup I want 4 plots per page. My current code only arranges them in a single column aligned to the left. Do you know how I can do this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out first - see if your pasted plots get arranged as you wanted:

```vb
Sub Graphics()
    
    Const START_TOP As Long = 2   'first shape top/left
    Const START_LEFT As Long = 5
    Const PER_ROW As Long = 2     'how many per row
    Const PER_GROUP As Long = 4   'how many per group
    Const ROOT As String = "\\ukfs1\users\gabriem\Documents\Misproyectos\BigPromotions\QAPromo\"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As ChartObject, shp As Shape
    Dim FileName As String, NewFileName As String
    Dim posTop As Long, posLeft As Long, i As Long

    FileName = ROOT & "graphicator.xlsx"
    NewFileName = ROOT & "test_pdf.pdf"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Negocios")
    Set wsTemp = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))

    i = 0
    posTop = START_TOP
    posLeft = START_LEFT
    
    For Each chrt In ws.ChartObjects
        i = i + 1
        chrt.CopyPicture
        wsTemp.Paste
        Set shp = wsTemp.Shapes(wsTemp.Shapes.Count)
        shp.Top = posTop
        shp.Left = posLeft
        
        'note: assumes all source graphs are the same size...
        If i Mod PER_ROW = 0 Then          'multiple of 2?
            posTop = posTop + shp.Height   'move down one row for next image
            posLeft = START_LEFT           'reset left position
        Else
            posLeft = posLeft + shp.Width  'move to right
        End If
        If i Mod PER_GROUP = 0 Then posTop = posTop + 20 'break between groups
    Next
    
    wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=NewFileName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    wsTemp.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thank you so much for your help! The arrangement is correct, is there any way I can make the PDF output a landscape? Currently my graphs are split over 2 pages I think making it landscape might help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Saving to PDF respects the page layout settings applied in Excel, so you need to set up your export sheet how you want it - including portrait/landscape.  If you want to be able to do that via VBA then try recording a macro while setting it up.