# Why is my Excel not being exported to PDF in Landscape?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Following Problem:

I have selected a range in excel and want to export it to a PDF. Given that it is quite wide and rather short, I want the pdf to be in landscape format. I've already tried this by setting the Page Layout --> Orientation to Landscape. But this does not work.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Excel2PDF()

    Dim BottomEquity As Range, BottomBond As Range, PDFArea As Range

    Set SB = Worksheets("SalesBrokerage")

    SB.Range("B2:N" & SB.Cells(SB.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Select

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\CustomerPrice.pdf", _ 
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True, Orientation:=Landscape

End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

**Bonus question:** Once I have set the landscape orientation (hopefully with your help), is there a way to ensure that the selected range fills the pdf page `BestFit`?

Comment: I can't see that there is an Orientation parameter. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118877/save-as-pdf-in-landscape

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save as PDF in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118877/save-as-pdf-in-landscape)

Comment: *But this does not work* is not helpful. What error message(s) do you get?