# How to save PDF in landscape and change paper size

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I need to change this "save to pdf" code into landscape and legal size.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub SavePDF()

    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & _
      ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".pdf"

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:K27"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=sFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You must do it separately, not trough the .pdf export.  You could do the page setup manually with macro recording, then see how to attack the issue in VBA.

Comment: But be aware of [The Macro Recorder Curse](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/) and `Application.DefaultFilePath` may differ from `ThisWorkbook.path`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SavePDF()

Dim sFile As String

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

sFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & _
    ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".pdf"

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:K27"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=sFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

[You can check a similar solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118877/save-as-pdf-in-landscape) if this isn't sufficient